# Openlayers 4: click do mouse para desenhar um ponto, faz mouse grudar na tela e provoca o arraste do mapa

Tags: click, openlayers-3

Olá, eu estou estudando o desenvolvimento de um mapa com a ajuda do Openlayers 4, vendo vídeo aulas, estou na fase em que criei uma rotina com 3 botões (Pan, Draw, Erase) para desenhar no mapa. Porém, quando eu clico no botão Draw, para criar uma feature do tipo Point, no lugar do clique, o cursor gruda no mapa, como se eu tivesse dado um clique duplo para iniciar a funçao Drag-and-drop. Só que eu apenas deu um clique, querendo colocar ali o ponto. Alguém sabe por que tá acontecendo isto?.

Answer (score 0):

Olha, consegui a solução! É que eu estava olhando um código num tutorial que usava apenas o ol.interaction.Draw, com o evento nomevarDraw.on('drawend', function(e){ ... etc. Bem, na documentação oficial do Openlayers.org, tem um exemplo que satisfez minha pesquisa, onde é usado o método Snap: var snap = new ol.interaction.Snap({source:source}). E depois desse método é aplicado, novamente, o comando map.addInteraction(snap). E parece que isso é mais atual para a versão 4. Funciona legal agora. Grato a quem se interessou.